# Javascript - typeof a primitive value is an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/n8emgLw9/

```
var a = [3, 6, 1, "str", 8];
$.each(a, function (i, e, x) {
console.log(this);
console.log(this + " is of type " + typeof this);
});
```

1) It logs as a primitive value in the first log entry, and then typeof logs as an object. Something is not right or it is a misnomer.

2) logging only "this"(first log statement) gives more details, but when logged in the second statement, it just prints the value. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not primitives. Compare:

```
console.log("foo", new String("foo"));
console.log(1,     new Number(1)    );
console.log(true,  new Boolean(true));
```

The first values are primitives; the second ones are objects that wrap primitives (i.e. boxed versions).

As to why it happens, `$.each` is implemented in terms of `Function.prototype.call`, which has this bit in its documentation ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)):

> The value of `this` provided for the call to *fun*. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, `null` and `undefined` will be replaced with the global object, and **primitive values will be boxed**.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: Yea, I thought so! But what does "primitive" in the log statement doing?

Comment: In my console, the output is e.g. `Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 1}`; this signifies it is an object with the constructor named `Number`. Its attributes include a special magic attribute `[[PrimitiveValue]]` whose value is the (now really primitive) number `1`. Compare with a non-magical case, `Dog {name: "Fido"}`, created from the constructor `Dog`, with an attribute `name` valued `"Fido"`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `call` or `apply` (what `$.each` does behind the scenes) and pass a primitive, JS implicitly "boxes" it into a corresponding object type:

```js
function foo() {
    document.write(typeof this);
    document.write(Object.prototype.toString.call(this));
}

foo.apply(123)
```

Reference: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3

> 3. <...> if Type(thisArg) is not Object, set the ThisBinding to ToObject(thisArg).

Comment: Yeah, makes more sense to link to ECMA standard rather than MDN, I suppose :)

Comment: @Amadan: yeah, happens all the time. You post a correct answer. Someone else edits their answer to reflect your point and gets all teh votez. Well, that's SO for you ;(

Comment: Well, you got my upvote. FWIW, I wasn't reading your answer, was busy editing and commenting on mine, then saw you made a similar point (even earlier than I did).

Comment: @Amadan: well, the rules are not well-defined, so everyone acts according to their personal understanding of fair sportsmanship ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `+` operator, js casts the whole thing to string.

What you probably want to use is:

```
console.log(this, " is of type " + typeof this);
```

with the comma.

Comment: Am afraid, it did not answer what i asked specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated code.
You may have expected this result than yours?

http://jsfiddle.net/n8emgLw9/1/

```
var a = [3, 6, 1, "str", 8];

for (var e in a){
    console.log(a[e]);
    console.log(a[e] + " is of type " + typeof a[e]);
}
```